# Iterate object properties from an object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

I have the following array given:

```
const myArray = [{ id: 1, isSet: true }, { id: 2, isSet: false }, ...];
```

Actually I want to iterate only the `isSet` properties of the objects (not all properties). The most simple solution, which came on my mind was the following:

```
let isSet = false;
for (const obj of myArray) {
    for (const property in obj) {
        if (property === "isSet" && obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            isSet |= obj[property];
        }
    }
}

console.log(isSet);
```

I think this one does not really look pretty, so has someone a better solution as the given one (maybe also better in runtime)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `allAreSet = myArray.every(x => x.isSet)` - this?

Comment: @georg this is a very good solution thx for the hint!

Comment: Georg's answer is correct, but even w/ manual iteration like you're doing, why wouldn't you just use `isSet |= obj.isSet` or similar? There's no need to iterate over all the properties in each object in the array.

Comment: @DaveNewton good hint. I used this syntax, because their could be multiple properties not only the isSet. (The isSet is just a placeholder e.g. it could also be an array with ["isSet", "id"] -> when I want to iterate all properties)

Comment: @georg It should be `.some()` instead of `.every()`. Based on the above code, I believe OP only cares if **any** of them are set, not if all of them are set

Comment: @KevinWallis What exactly are the conditions you are testing for? `isSet === truthy`, `id === ???`, etc.?

Comment: @mhodges actually I am testing, if any `isSet === true`. Their will be the option to add additional properties to evaluate, but I am only checking the isSet at the moment. So you are right with the `.some()` function.

Comment: @KevinWallis Right, so will you be passing in the logic for those via a comparator function or something? Or will it be hard-coded knowledge of each condition?

Comment: @mhodges the evaluation criteria will be passed in by an evaluation function, which could be combined with `.some()`.

Comment: @KevinWallis Gotcha, check out my answer and let me know if that is what you're looking for.

Comment: @mhodges: **all**AreSet = ....every, I thought that's clear enough.

Comment: @georg very clear, just not what the OP was needing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this generically if you pass in your set of rules for each property, like so:

```js
const myArray1 = [{ id: 1, isSet: false }, { id: 2, isSet: false }, { id: 3, isSet: false }];

// check if there is an object with id = 3, isSet = true
var conditions = {
  isSet: (obj) => obj.isSet,
  id: (obj) => obj.id === 3
};
// check if there is an object with id = 2, isSet = false
var conditions2 = {
  isSet: (obj) => !obj.isSet,
  id: (obj) => obj.id === 2
};

function testConditions(arr, conditions) {
  // .some() -- do ANY of the objects match the criteria?
  return arr.some(obj => {
    // .every() -- make sure ALL conditions are true for any given object
    return Object.keys(conditions).every(key => {
      // run comparitor function for each key for the given object
      return conditions[key](obj);
    });
  });
}

console.log(testConditions(myArray1, conditions)); // false -- no object with id = 3, isSet = true
console.log(testConditions(myArray1, conditions2)); // true -- myArray1[1] has id = 2, isSet = false
```

Comment: Thanks this looks quite handsome and is exactly what I searched for!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `some` function of an array.

```js
const myArray1 = [{ id: 1, isSet: false }, { id: 2, isSet: false }, { id: 3, isSet: false }];

let isSet1 = myArray1.some(obj => obj.isSet === true)

console.log(isSet1);

const myArray2 = [{ id: 1, isSet: false }, { id: 2, isSet: true }, { id: 3, isSet: false }];

let isSet2 = myArray2.some(obj => obj.isSet === true)

console.log(isSet2);
```

Comment: this is exactly what `.some()` is for. `var isSet1 = myArray1.some(obj => obj.isSet)`

Comment: Why create new array with `filter()`?

Comment: woops! I forgot about that.